# Loading .nc file in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with opening .nc files.
I tried with several files (named L3 and L5) and it works for L3 but not for L5.

[The code works for L3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs0qj.png)

[The code does not work for L5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7gbH.png)

The error message is as follows for L5:
'''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_442/1488629900.py in 
1 # select one site (Howard Springs)
----> 2 ds = xr.open_mfdataset(eddy_files[0])
3 ds_orig = ds.copy()
4 # Filtering out data gaps marked as -9999
5 ds = ds_orig.where(ds_orig != -9999.)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in open_mfdataset(paths, chunks, concat_dim, compat, preprocess, engine, data_vars, coords, combine, parallel, join, attrs_file, combine_attrs, **kwargs)
906         getattr_ = getattr
907
--> 908     datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
909     closers = [getattr_(ds, "_close") for ds in datasets]
910     if preprocess is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in (.0)
906         getattr_ = getattr
907
--> 908     datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
909     closers = [getattr_(ds, "_close") for ds in datasets]
910     if preprocess is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in open_dataset(filename_or_obj, engine, chunks, cache, decode_cf, mask_and_scale, decode_times, decode_timedelta, use_cftime, concat_characters, decode_coords, drop_variables, backend_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
477
478     if engine is None:
--> 479         engine = plugins.guess_engine(filename_or_obj)
480
481     backend = plugins.get_backend(engine)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/plugins.py in guess_engine(store_spec)
153         )
154
--> 155     raise ValueError(error_msg)
156
157

ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['netcdf4', 'scipy']. Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed engines via the `engine` parameter, or installing additional IO dependencies, see:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/getting-started-guide/installing.html
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html
'''

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was due to incorrect loading of files - Problem solved